# argocd apphealth says healthy but liveness probe is failing in a loop

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

In the argocd UI event logs I can see that "Unhealthy Liveness probe failed", but besides that, argo reports it's healthy and has a green heart attached to the pod. What am i doing wrong?

Shouldn't argocd show a symbol, that the app is unhealthy?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot? Specifically which resource is marked healthy which should be marked degraded? A Pod?

Comment: Hello there,  it was due to me not placing a readiness probe in the deployment description. After having a readiness probe as well it gets degraded as expected.